# Show $\min(X_1,...,X_n)-1/n$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$.

Tags: statistics, order-statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be independent copies of a real-valued random variable $X$ where $X$ has Lebesgue density

\begin{align*}
p_\theta(x) = \begin{cases} \exp(\theta-x),\quad x>\theta  \\ 
0, \quad\quad\quad\quad\;\ x\leq \theta, \end{cases}
\end{align*}
where $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$ is an unknown parameter.
Let $S:=\min(X_1,...,X_n)$.

claim: $S-1/n$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$.

I tried the following: to show that $\text{bias}_\theta(S-1/n)=0$, by definition, we need to show that $\mathbb{E}_\theta[S-1/n]=\theta$, so

$\mathbb{E}_\theta[S-1/n]=\mathbb{E}_\theta[X_{(1)}]-1/n=\int_\theta^{\infty}x\exp{(\theta-x)}dx-1/n=e^\theta(\theta+1)e^{-\theta}-1/n=\theta+1-1/n$,

can someone help me and tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You considered the pdf of $\min\{X_1,\cdots,X_n\}$ as the same of $X_i$. In fact:$$F_{\min\{X_1,\cdots,X_n\}}(x)=1-(1-P_\theta(x))^n\\
f_{\min\{X_1,\cdots,X_n\}}(x)=n\cdot p_\theta(x)(1-P_\theta(x))^{n-1}
$$

Comment: You're right, thanks! But shouldn't it be $f_{\min\{ X_1,...,X_n \}}(x)=np_{\theta}(x)(1-P_\theta(x))^{n-1}$? The $n$ comes from taking the derivative of $F_{\min\{ X_1,...,X_n\}}(x)$.

Comment: Sorry. I don't get it :(

Comment: I think your answer is correct, just the $n$ in the pdf is missing, isnt' it?

Comment: Yes it was. Tnx!